# How to detect the computer which sent data to printer?

Tags: wireless-networking, printing, printer, network-printer

We have an HP printer at the office. It is connected to Wireless + LAN, so there are a couple of computers which you can send data to the printer to print. If there is a suspicious acitivity like printing unnecessary data and we don't know which computer does it, can we detect the computer which sent the data to printer? How?

The printer is: HP Color Laserjet Pro MFP M177fw

Comment: Is this a network printer you guys connect to through a server?

Comment: If you ask that there is a special server for this printer; no, there is no dedicated server or something like it as a printer server. Everyone can send data to print on the LAN (+wireless) directly

Comment: Okay, do you have the ability to access the WebUI of the printer?  (Use a browser to connect to the IP address of the printer.)  There may be an event log on there somewhere you can refer to.

Comment: I see that there is no IP address shown, it looks like it connects via WSD...

Comment: Are you able to ping the printer name? (Open cmd and type `ping [printer name]`)  It should return an IP address that it is currently using.  (The printer should still have an IP address even though it is through a WSD port)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't ping via name. I'll try to get IP but is there a "WebUI" for this model exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55478/discussion-between-cheesus-crust-and-yasin-okumus).